# VUE CLI - How to import scripts and styles

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Please I have been trying to import local styles and javascript files into my newly created VUE-CLI 3 application (inside public/index.hml) but they are not reflecting in my components.

Using Vue-cli 2 it works.

Are we not supposed to import css and styles in public/index.hml
Please how do i get this to work?
Please help.

See below how i referenced the files in public/index.html file

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
<title>vue-cameleon</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Common CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/assets/css/main.css" />

    <!-- Other CSS includes plugins - Cleanedup unnecessary CSS -->
    <!-- Chartist css -->
    <link href="../src/assets/vendor/chartist/css/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../src/assets/vendor/chartist/css/chartist-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 14):

You could import them in the `main.js` as follows :

```
  import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
  import  './assets/css/main.css'
  ....
```

or in `App.vue` :

```
 <template>...</template>
 <script>...</script>
 <style src='./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'></style>
 <style src='./assets/css/main.css'></style>
```

Comment: However, when I try importing heavy external css files and javascript libraries, I keeo getting this error message 

./src/assets/fonts/opensans/opensans-regular-webfont.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <!DOCTYPE html>
| <html>
| <body>

Any idea why and what could be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using the vue-cli v4, go to your main.js file and add the imports of your js/css files like this

```
import './assets/main.js'
import './assets/main.css'
```

And make sure you have put those file in the assets folder of your project!