# How to use external scss files in NativeScript-Vue

Tags: vue.js, sass, nativescript-vue

I have 2 external I want to use in my `Nativescript-Vue` files.

They are located in the following directory `/app/styles/_variables.sccs` and `/app/styles/generalStyles.scss`.

I import `_variables.sccs` in `generalStyles.sccs`.

But when I want to import `generalStyles.sccs` in my Vue file it gives me the following error:

> SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: styles/generalStyles.
>           on line 277 of app/components/Select/StationSelect.vue
>
> > @import "styles/generalStyles";

StationSelect.vue looks like this

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

    @import "styles/generalStyles";

    .routeDetailsChoice,
    .timeDetails{
        Label,
        TextField{

            .ns-dark &{
                color: $white;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

I have also the following packages:

```
"nativescript-vue": "2.4.0",
"node-sass": "^4.13.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.1",
"style-loader": "^1.1.3",
```

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671245/vue-cli-3-how-to-import-scripts-and-styles/52671590#52671590)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim sorry I tried and it doesn't work either. It gives the error that he can't find the styles. And the other problems I would also not be able to use the variables from _variables.scss.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack comes configured with some aliases that point to the root folder of your project. Try `@import "app/styles/generalStyles";` or `@import "~/styles/generalStyles";` or import from a relative path.