# VueJS adding javascript files via <script> tag in index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs2, include

I'm trying to include some scripts to my vue app. but all that i've tried so far didn't work.

I'm using Vue 2 and created my project with the vue CLI.

when i try just adding the script tags to my index.html

```
<script src="../src/assets/js/typewriter-effect.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../src/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Which i later understood from a post:

> So if you are running the local dev server for instance, the browser
> tries to load the file being served at
> http://localhost:8080/~some-npm-package/path/to/lib.js.
>
> The dev server is setup to just serve whatever is in the index.html
> regardless of the actual URL, so it serves the index.html when you try
> and fetch http://localhost:8080/~some-npm-package/path/to/lib.js.
>
> The browser tries to read this file as a script but the first line of
> the index.html file is  - hence the SyntaxError:
> expected expression, got '<' that you see.

So my workaround was to use CDN, but even though I could see form devTools that the script was loaded, it didnt work on the page, there was no change. Besides, some of my scripts are only available locally and not from CDNs.

I tried importing in main.js

```
import './assets/js/slick.min.js'
import './assets/js/custom.js'
```

or from App.vue

But that didnt seem to work.

Comment: See this [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671245/vue-cli-how-to-import-scripts-and-styles)

Comment: @Tim Tried that already.

Comment: when you say importing in main.js doesn't work, what does it happen, did it shows you an error?
are you sure that you have your files on src/assets/js/

Comment: @jc.vargas.valencia there is no error; but the expected behaviour, doesnt happen. for instance, i use a carousel library, but the carousel is not effective.

Comment: Have you try to install the carousel by npm: 
npm install slick-carousel
and import it in your component as import 'slick-carousel';

I have use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slick-carousel on some vue projects you can git it a try.

Comment: Did you check https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder ? Put it to public. Load it as src="<%= BASE_URL %>...". End of the story.

Comment: @jc.vargas.valencia I have not tried to install the npm module even though I saw it because this solution will not work with all my scripts, what if there is no vue module for a particular library, i need a solution that will work for all.

Comment: Do you just want the scripts to run i.e. ```import 'myscript.js'```, or do you need to access variables, functions,etc. i.e. ```import myscript from 'myscript.js'```, then call ```myscript.myfunction()```.  Regardless, if you haven't also tried this already, take a look at [Importing javascript file for use within vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426972/importing-javascript-file-for-use-within-vue-component)